# Move/Copy A File Using Microsoft Flow With Dynamic Destination

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, microsoft

Is it possible yet to move or copy a file from a document library in SharePoint Online to another destination document library using Microsoft Flow where the user can select the destination document library?

(Note: I can use Microsoft Flow to move or copy a file but the key part of this question is that the **user can select the destination document library**)

Answer (score 1):

I succeed with a sample flow to move file with a drop-down list destination selection. 
[image]

Two things to note:

1. You may have find that the "For a selected file" action will not provide dynamic content to get file properties(identifier). You will need to type in `triggerBody()?['entity']?['FileId']` manually to add the highlighted Id. Check here:https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/New-trigger-For-a-selected-file-ID-no-dynamic-content-yet/td-p/279519
2. You may not have different columns in the two libraries. I always get error when the origin library has some custom columns. Not very sure about this. And the process may take a bit time(28s for a simple docx file in my end)

Comment: In your example, how does the dropdown list of options link to the available document library locations available to the user?

Comment: @motionpotion It is done manually. We will have to type in a destination path by hand. I did not find a better approach to make it populated automatically. Just by the way. If the only goal is to move files to another library, the move to button in modern experience seems to be a better choice.

Comment: but typing them in manually doesn't link them to the existing locations either. The reason I'm looking at Flow for this is because the Copy To and Move To options does not work for External Guest users. As it turns out, during the process of investigating this Flow option, I have discovered that Flow does not work for External Guest users either.

Comment: @motionpotion Yes you are correct, the external users are not able to use flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.... MS flow supports passing data to flow by user..

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/button-user-inputs/

You can take different type of inputs like text, number, file,email etc... So you can use input text to ask user to enter document library url. Please note that you won't able to provide UI which allows user to select document library. They have to manually enter destination url. In you MS flow you can read this user input parameter to set your destination library